# How can I change properties of a JTabbedpane component at run time?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, jcomponent

I am creating a tabbedpane

```
tabs= new JTabbedPane();
tabs.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
          JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
          int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
          sourceTabbedPane.getTabComponentAt(index).getComponentAt(0).setForeground(Color.RED);

});

tabs.setTabComponentAt(0, new JLabel("tab1"));
tabs.setTabComponentAt(0, new JLabel("tab2"));
```

I get this error:

*The method getComponentAt(Point) in the type Component is not applicable for the arguments (int)*

How do I get hold of the LABEL I put on the selectedTab? I want to set the foreground on the label.

```
EDIT 1
```

I also get a null pointer error at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`Component.getComponentAt` accepts a `Point` object or two integers as `int x, int y`, that it looks for child components at that location.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html

Comment: Yes. I read that before and I tried (0,0) and (1,1) -  worked neither

Comment: Is your JLabel at position (0, 0)? This is not the index, physical location in pixels.

Comment: actually see my edit - I seem to be getting a null pointer error. I guess that must be on "index"

Comment: Yes, since getComponentAt cannot find any components at (0,0) it's returning null. And you're trying to set foreground color on a null reference.